# why can't ofstream open a file in my cern root macro?

Tags: c++, macros, root-framework

I have a macro for CERN's ROOT (v5.34.32) saved to mscwreader.C :

```
#include <fstream>
void mscwreader( char * outputtext )
{ 
  ofstream myfile ;
  cout << "Opening file" << endl;
  cout << outputtext << endl;
  myfile.open( outputtext, ios::in|ios::out ) ;
  if ( myfile.is_open() )
  {
    myfile << "test\n" ;
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return ;
}
```

which I run with the command

```
$ root -b -l -q -x "mscwreader.C(\"/path/to/my/output.txt\")"
```

But the macro can't open the file, outputting this:

```
Processing     mscwreader.C("/path/to/my/output.txt")...
Opening file
/path/to/my/output.txt
Unable to open file
```

I have write permissions (drwxr-xr-x) to the directory.  Why can't I open the file for writing?

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault.  The input /path/to/my/output.txt had an extra character, so the directory it was trying to open didn't technically exist.